# Open .sci and .sce file in macOS

Tags: scilab

I can run Scilab properly but I'm trying to open .sci and .sce files in macOS Sonoma 14.2.1, but the computer does not let me choose scilab from the apps to open them, what can I do? Is there another file type?

Tried drag and drop, open with etc, did not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

until now macOS cannot directly open .sce or .sci files directly from the finder. You have to either open the files from within Scilab or drag and drop files in Scilab's command window.